# Can you design a custom loss function such that early time-points receive a larger weight than later ones?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, time-series

I am training a neural network (NN) to predict time-series evolution. X_train is N*M, where N is the number of examples and M is the number of initial conditions. y_train is NxP where P is the number of time-points for the evolution of the dependent variable. I would like to give the columns with the earlier time-points in y_train a larger weight during training so that the NN is more likely to predict earlier time-points correctly. Is there a way to do this with keras? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can always create your custom loss function

```
def custom_loss(target_y, predicted_y):
    losses = tf.abs(target_y - predicted_y) # we are modifying the Mean Absolute Error (MAE)
    weights = tf.range(1, 0, delta=-1/P) # you can customize your weights, this is just an example
    return tf.reduce_mean(losses * weights)

model = create_model(...)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=custom_loss, metrics=['mae'])
```